# How to set Microsoft Graph API permissions on Azure Managed Service Identity with PowerShell 7

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-powershell, powershell-core

To grant Microsoft Graph API permissions to a User-Assigned Managed Service Identity or System-Assigned Managed Service Identity, one has to use PowerShell. All the articles I can find (e.g. [this](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/integrations-on-azure-blog/grant-graph-api-permission-to-managed-identity-object/ba-p/2792127)) point to using the `New-AzureAdServiceAppRoleAssignment` cmdlet from the `AzureAD` PowerShell module, however, this module doesn't support anything newer than Windows PowerShell version 5.1 and as I need to complete the task on a Linux-based build agent, I need to find a way supported by PowerShell (core).

Looking at the last update date of `AzureAD`, I suspect MS aren't planning on updating it further and besides a lot of the functionality has already moved to the `Az` PowerShell module, however, the critical cmdlet doesn't appear to have made it across. (`AzureADPreview` has the same issues). I am not sure which direction Microsoft are heading, but to confuse matters, there is the `Microsoft.Graph` module; more specifically `Microsoft.Graph.Applications`. Reviewing the list of cmdlets in the module, the most likely candidate to achieve the same task is `New-MgServicePrincipalAppRoleAssignment`, however, I cannot get it to work.

The following is the `AzureAD` Windows PowerShell (5.1) way (that works with the new `Az` cmdlets):

```
$DestinationTenantId = "a3186524-d3d5-4820-8cb5-9ad21badb14a"
$MsiName = "myUserMSI" # Name of system-assigned or user-assigned managed service identity. (System-assigned use same name as resource)

# Graph API permissions to set
$oPermissions = @(
  "Directory.ReadWrite.All"
  "Group.ReadWrite.All"
)

$GraphAppId = "00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000" # Don't change this.

$oMsi = Get-AzADServicePrincipal -Filter "displayName eq '$MsiName'"
$oGraphSpn = Get-AzADServicePrincipal -Filter "appId eq '$GraphAppId'"

$oAppRole = $oGraphSpn.AppRole | Where-Object {($_.Value -in $oPermissions) -and ($_.AllowedMemberType -contains "Application")}

Connect-AzureAD -TenantId $DestinationTenantId

foreach($AppRole in $oAppRole)
{
    New-AzureAdServiceAppRoleAssignment `
      -ObjectId $oMsi.Id `
      -PrincipalId $oMsi.Id `
      -ResourceId $oGraphSpn.Id `
      -Id $AppRole.Id `
      -Verbose
}
```

Here is my attempt at using the `Microsoft.Graph.Applications` module with PowerShell (v.7.2.5).

```
$DestinationTenantId = "a3186524-d3d5-4820-8cb5-9ad21badb14a"
$MsiName = "myUserMSI" # Name of system-assigned or user-assigned managed service identity. (System-assigned use same name as resource)

$oPermissions = @(
  "Directory.ReadWrite.All"
  "Group.ReadWrite.All"
  "GroupMember.ReadWrite.All"
  "User.ReadWrite.All"
  "RoleManagement.ReadWrite.Directory"
)

$GraphAppId = "00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000" # Don't change this.

$oMsi = Get-AzADServicePrincipal -Filter "displayName eq '$MsiName'"
$oGraphSpn = Get-AzADServicePrincipal -Filter "appId eq '$GraphAppId'"

$oAppRole = $oGraphSpn.AppRole | Where-Object {($_.Value -in $oPermissions) -and ($_.AllowedMemberType -contains "Application")}

Connect-MgGraph -TenantId $DestinationTenantId

foreach($AppRole in $oAppRole)
{
  $oAppRoleAssignment = @{
    "PrincipalId" = $oMSI.Id
    "ResourceId" = $GraphAppId
    "AppRoleId" = $AppRole.Id
  }
  
  New-MgServicePrincipalAppRoleAssignment `
    -ServicePrincipalId $oAppRoleAssignment.PrincipalId `
    -BodyParameter $oAppRoleAssignment `
    -Verbose
}
```

This results in the following error:

```
PS C:\> . "Set-ApiPermissionsForMI.ps1"
VERBOSE: Performing the operation "New-MgServicePrincipalAppRoleAssignment_Create1" on target "Call remote 'ServicePrincipalsCreateAppRoleAssignments1' operation".
New-MgServicePrincipalAppRoleAssignment_Create1: C:\Set-ApiPermissionsForMI.ps1:36:3
Line |
  36 |    New-MgServicePrincipalAppRoleAssignment `
     |    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | Resource '00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000' does not exist or one of its queried reference-property objects are not present.
```

I see it's complaining that the "special" service principal for MS Graph is missing, but as the `AzureAD` cmdlet worked, I know it is correct, but I don't know if this cmdlet is even the correct replacement - if there even is a replacement that works with PowerShell core.

If anyone has a solution for my problem, I'd be very grateful if you could share, please.

T.I.A.

## Update 1

I've found [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/microsoftgraph/azuread-msoline-cmdlet-map?view=graph-powershell-1.0#service-principals) document describing the mapping of `AzureAD` to `Microsoft.Graph` cmdlets. I have the correct cmdlet:

| AzureAD | Microsoft.Graph.Applications |
| --- | --- |
| New-AzureADServiceAppRoleAssignment | New-MgServicePrincipalAppRoleAssignment |

The document also confirms that Microsoft are replacing the `AzureAD` module with the `Microsoft.Graph` module.

Answer (score 2):

Long day! The problem was between chair and keyboard! Here is the working solution:

```
$DestinationTenantId = "a3186524-d3d5-4820-8cb5-9ad21badb14a"
$MsiName = "myUserMSI" # Name of system-assigned or user-assigned managed service identity. (System-assigned use same name as resource).

$oPermissions = @(
  "Directory.ReadWrite.All"
  "Group.ReadWrite.All"
  "GroupMember.ReadWrite.All"
  "User.ReadWrite.All"
  "RoleManagement.ReadWrite.Directory"
)

$GraphAppId = "00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000" # Don't change this.

$oMsi = Get-AzADServicePrincipal -Filter "displayName eq '$MsiName'"
$oGraphSpn = Get-AzADServicePrincipal -Filter "appId eq '$GraphAppId'"

$oAppRole = $oGraphSpn.AppRole | Where-Object {($_.Value -in $oPermissions) -and ($_.AllowedMemberType -contains "Application")}

Connect-MgGraph -TenantId $DestinationTenantId

foreach($AppRole in $oAppRole)
{
  $oAppRoleAssignment = @{
    "PrincipalId" = $oMSI.Id
    #"ResourceId" = $GraphAppId
    "ResourceId" = $oGraphSpn.Id
    "AppRoleId" = $AppRole.Id
  }
  
  New-MgServicePrincipalAppRoleAssignment `
    -ServicePrincipalId $oAppRoleAssignment.PrincipalId `
    -BodyParameter $oAppRoleAssignment `
    -Verbose
}
```

The problem was in the hashtable `$oAppRoleAssignment.ResourceId`.
It should be `$oGraphSpn.Id` and not `$GraphAppId`. I was passing the App ID, not the SPN ID of the App.

### Automated authentication.

You may have noticed the `Connect-MgGraph` cmdlet. As I mentioned in the question, this will need to work on a build agent and therefore I need automated credentials. Microsoft have decided to make us jump through a bunch of hoops. We can't pass it a PSCredential object. We have to create another certificate-based SPN and set up the public and private keys. I haven't done this bit yet, but there is a guide [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/microsoftgraph/app-only?view=graph-powershell-1.0&tabs=azure-portal).

There is an open issue on Github [here](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-powershell/issues/1366). If you'd like `Connect-MgGraph` to support `-Credential` please consider giving it the thumbs up.

#### Secret-Based SPN

Here's how to authenticate with a secret-based SPN:

```
# Replace below with your details (these are not the actual GUIDs).
$appid = '1a0f530d-e288-4f71-9870-f72e0079e6c3'
$tenantid = '9734136b-c9d8-43f7-9c99-29737c23e5c9'
$secret = '<YOUR-CLIENT-SECRET>'

 
$body =  @{
    Grant_Type    = "client_credentials"
    Scope         = "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"
    Client_Id     = $appid
    Client_Secret = $secret
}
 
$connection = Invoke-RestMethod `
    -Uri https://login.microsoftonline.com/$tenantid/oauth2/v2.0/token `
    -Method POST `
    -Body $body
 
$token = $connection.access_token
 
Connect-MgGraph -AccessToken $token
```

Source: https://helloitsliam.com/2022/04/20/connect-to-microsoft-graph-powershell-using-an-app-registration/

Remember to assign the Service Principal (SPN) the required Graph API *Application* permissions in Azure AD.

### Side note:

There is the [Add-AzAdAppPermission](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/add-azadapppermission?view=azps-8.1.0) cmdlet, but, unfortunately, it appears this only works for AD applications as opposed to MSIs. I tried running it, but it errored, unable to find my `ObjectID`.

Comment: Did you get this to work for a user assigned managed identity? (Or just a system assigned managed identity?)

Comment: @DonnyKwitty,The above PS works but I found I had to add '-Scopes "AppRoleAssignment.ReadWrite.All", "Directory.Read.All"' to the Connect-MgGraph commandlet for the New-MgServicePrincipalAppRoleAssignment commandlet not to error out with a permissions error.  
Also, you need to have the Global Admin role too.