# How to Assign Microsoft Graph API Permissions to a User Assigned Managed Identity?

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I have a user assigned managed identity that's associated with VM resource and I want to assign several Graph API permissions to. Most everything I find online is uses a system assigned identity. When I follow the instructions, I get an insufficient privileges error even when I try with Global Administrator.

Is this scenario even supported?

I tried following this existing question: [How to set Microsoft Graph API permissions on Azure Managed Service Identity with PowerShell 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72904838/how-to-set-microsoft-graph-api-permissions-on-azure-managed-service-identity-wit)

Comment: You can't assign Graph permissions to a user: you assign them to an app registration (where you choose for Delegated or Application permissions, based on what you need)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to Assign Microsoft Graph API Permissions to a User Assigned Managed Identity?

Here is the `PowerShell script` to assign **Permissions** to **User Managed Identity**

```
    Connect-AzureAD
    
    $TenantID = "TenantID"
    $GraphAppId = "00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000" # Don't change this value
    $NameOfMSI = "venkat-user-identity"
    $Permissions = @(
        "Directory.Read.All",
        "Directory.ReadWrite.All",
        "Group.ReadWrite.All",
        "GroupMember.ReadWrite.All",
        "User.ReadWrite.All",
        "RoleManagement.ReadWrite.Directory"
    )
    
    $MSI = (Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -Filter "displayName eq '$NameOfMSI'")
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 10
    $GraphServicePrincipal = Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -Filter "appId eq '$GraphAppId'"
    
    foreach ($PermissionName in $Permissions) {
        $AppRole = $GraphServicePrincipal.AppRoles | Where-Object { $_.Value -eq $PermissionName -and $_.AllowedMemberTypes -contains "Application" }
        New-AzureAdServiceAppRoleAssignment -ObjectId $MSI.ObjectId -PrincipalId $MSI.ObjectId -ResourceId $GraphServicePrincipal.ObjectId -Id $AppRole.Id
    }
```

**Output**

[image]

`Graph API` permissions assigned successfully to `User Managed Identity`

[image]

Reference:  [How to use managed identities for App Service and Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-managed-identity?tabs=portal,powershell#connect-to-azure-services-in-app-code)

Comment: Thank you for the reply, @venkat-v. Unfortunately this still doesn't work for me. I get the same insufficient privileges error.

Comment: I tried again while permissioned as a Global Administrator and it worked! I had to restart the virtual machine that the managed identity is assigned to, but then it worked as expected.