# How to grant delegate access to a specific O365 Shared Mailboxes for a System Managed Identity

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, office365, microsoft-graph-mail, exchange-online

Would it be possible for a System Managed Identity to be granted delegate access to **certain** Office 365 Shared Mailboxes, then query them using Graph API?

I have an Azure Automation runbook running a PowerShell script that has the necessity to access the Calendar contents of such mailboxes.

Since it's a runbook, it's running unattended, I know I could grant [Calendars.Read](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference#calendarsread) **application API permissions** but that would require the addition of creating a secret and then setting up an **Application Access Policy** to prevent the runbook from accessing **all** the mailboxes across the organization.

Instead of that, it would be beautiful to just grant delegated access to the required mailboxes to the System Managed Identity, just like we can do with normal users, using the `Add-MailboxPermission -User <xxxx@xxx.xxx>` PowerShell command and access those without any added complexity.

I tried to run the `Add-MailboxPermission -User` command passing the **Object (principal) id** (GUID) of the System Managed Identity, but that didn't work.

Comment: AFAIK you cannot assign delegated permissions to managed identity only application type permissions can be assigned. You would not be able to sign in as a user with the Managed Identity

Comment: And try Add-MailboxPermission -Identity email@domain.com -User <Managed Identity Object Id> -AccessRights FullAccess

Comment: Yeas, that's the command we usually run, but it doesn't seem to work when passing a Managed Identity Object Id as parameter: 
`Microsoft.Exchange.Configuration. Tasks.ManagementObjectNotFoundExceptionlUser or group "[GUID]" wasn't found. Please make sure you've typed it correctly.`

Answer (score 0):

I created a web app and enabled **system assigned identity**:

[image]

Check whether the user has mailbox:

```
Connect-ExchangeOnline

Get-Mailbox -Identity user@xxx.onmicrosoft.com
```

[image]

When I tried to run the **`Add-MailboxPermission`** command by passing the `ObjectID` I got the **same error**:

```
Add-MailboxPermission -Identity user@xxx.onmicrosoft.com -User ManagedIdentityObjectId -AccessRights FullAccess
```

[image]

**To resolve the error**, you need to explicitly create the service principal by passing the `ObjectID` and the `ApplicationID` like below:

*Search the system managed identity Enterprise application:*

[image]

```
New-ServicePrincipal -AppId EnterpriseApplicationApplicationID -ServiceId EnterpriseApplicationObjectId
```

[image]

Now **to add the Mailbox Permission to the managed identity**, copy  `ObjectID` from the response and pass it in the user parameter:

```
Add-MailboxPermission -Identity user@xxx.onmicrosoft.com -User ObjectId -AccessRights FullAccess
```

[image]

You can **verify** by using below command:

```
Get-MailboxPermission -Identity user@xxx.onmicrosoft.com -User EnterpriseApplicationObjectId
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the valuable information, I think you pointed me in the right direction.
I have one more question, with the approach you described, where do you specify the permissions the Managed Identity will gain over the mailbox that's being authorized?

Like, in case I want to connect to Microsoft Graph using the Managed Identity.

Comment: Yes you can assign Microsoft Graph permissions to the managed identity refer https://mmsharepoint.wordpress.com/2023/05/19/assign-microsoft-graph-permissions-to-managed-identities-the-potentially-leanest-way/

Comment: OR refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72904838/how-to-set-microsoft-graph-api-permissions-on-azure-managed-service-identity-wit

Comment: I will try this very soon. Thank you!